# XOR Operation C++/Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, bitwise-operators, cpu-architecture, bitwise-xor

This is a code that's doing XOR operations.
The code is doing like x.bits.b = x.bits.c ^ x.bits.a
What I want is that: x.bits.c = x.bits.a ^ x.bits.b

I tried to change all of "cl" values to "bl" and it did not work.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
typedef union {
    unsigned char BYTE;
    struct {
        unsigned char a : 1;
        unsigned char b : 3;
        unsigned char c : 4;
    }bits;
}un_X;

un_X x;

x.BYTE = 0xFE;
x.bits.a = 1;
x.bits.b = 0;
x.bits.c = 2;


printf("\n");
printf("BYTE = %X\n", x.BYTE);
printf("   a = %d\n", x.bits.a);
printf("   b = %d\n", x.bits.b);
printf("   c = %d\n", x.bits.c);



_asm {
    //unsigned char a = x.BYTE & 0x01;
    mov al, x.BYTE
    and al, 0x01
    // unsigned char c = (x.BYTE & 0xF0) >> 4;
    mov cl, x.BYTE
    and cl, 0xF0
    shr cl, 4
    //unsigned char b = c ^ a;
    xor al, cl
    // x.BYTE &= 0xF1; // 1111 0001
    mov dl, x.BYTE
    and dl, 0xF1
    // x.BYTE |= (b << 1);
    shl al, 1
    or dl, al
    mov x.BYTE, dl

}





printf("\n");
printf("BYTE = %X\n", x.BYTE);
printf("   a = %d\n", x.bits.a);
printf("   b = %d\n", x.bits.b);
printf("   c = %d\n", x.bits.c);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I expect to a and b is constant and c is variable.

Comment: please explain what you mean with "it did not work"

Comment: @user463035818: *"The code is doing like x.bits.b = x.bits.c ^ x.bits.a What I want is that: x.bits.c = x.bits.a ^ x.bits.b"*

Comment: Please include expected and actual output in the question

Comment: @user463035818: Damn, man.  It's in the question.

Comment: This title is infuriatingly vague. What is the problem here? Why is assembly necessary and not just C++? Tip: Write C++ and *look at the assembly output* from the compiler. Use that as a basis for your own code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did read the question. The question tries to explain what output is expected, nevertheless I think it would help if the expected output was explicitly included in the question. I dont think starting a discussion on the clarity / completeness of the question helps anybody. If you think it is obvious, then go ahead and write an answer. I could not do it, hence I asked for clarification.

Comment: Expected: BYTE = 21
   a = 1
   b = 0
   c = 2

BYTE = 27
   a = 1
   b = 0
   c = 1                   
Actual: BYTE = 21
   a = 1
   b = 0
   c = 2

BYTE = 27
   a = 1
   b = 3
   c = 2

Comment: @user8889711 all question clarifications should go into the question itself, not comments.

Comment: You can’t just change the names, you need to use the correct shifts and masks as well.

Comment: I don't get it.. You apparently know how to isolate the `c` bits, so why is doing that with the `b` bits a problem? It's just a different bitmask and shift amount.

Comment: Why do you not let the compiler doing ? Be sure it will does fine ! Look at the assembler generated for `x.bits.c = x.bits.a ^ x.bits.b;` (do that in an other function else the compiler will directly place the values from the constants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a bitwise AND with `0xF1` to clear out some bits of `x.BYTE`, then OR in the value of `al` shifted left by 1, the bits that get populated are the first three bits of `c`, aka the lower nibble of `x.BYTE`. This gives us:

```
0001
 XOR
0011
----
0010
```

Which has the value 2, explaining the output. As for `b`, since it occupies bits 1..4 of `x.BYTE`, and you want `b` to have the value zero, just do a bitwise AND on those bits:

```
 mov al, x.BYTE
 and al, 0x8F
```

Comment: I did do that at the beginning of asm code. Same result.

Comment: @user8889711 I don't see the value `0x8F` anywhere in your code, or equivalent bit operations to grab bits 1 to 4.

Comment: But sir, where do i have to put them?